# Dragging object on Storyboard or .xib always puts it inside object underneath. Why?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xib

I have a ScrollView filling my View. I have some other things on top. When I try re-position the ones on top, Xcode insists on putting them inside the ScrollView. Is there a key I can press or something to stop this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mikeydelamonde,

I have wondered the same thing and was initially frustrated by this behavior.  So I would be interested in hearing other responses as well.  But I can share a few tricks that might help.

1. Know that the order of the objects in your view determies the z-order priority.  If you need to work on a particular object, just move it up or down to make it on the top of the stack.  If you inadvertently place objects inside of each other, you can move the around in the object tree view to put it inside the correct view.
2. Know that you can temporarily hide and resize objects to allow other objects to be accessible/visible while you are positioning/editing.
3. Know that once you get an object on the storyboard or .xib, you can move them around with the arrow keys and by explicitly setting the x, y, width, height.  Although this seems like too manual of a process, I found it really isn't that bad and allows me to get things lined up just the way I want it.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just one of Xcode's many quirks. Try pulling the listing of the element in the left bar up above your Scroll View, it should place the element above the Scroll View.